# Reading data from Firebase in a React Native Application

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a simple application in react native and attempting to read data from my firebase firestore. Here is my firebase config .js file

```
import firebase, { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
}

const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const FIREBASE_AUTH = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP)
const FIREBASE_FIRESTORE = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);

export { FIREBASE_APP, FIREBASE_AUTH, FIREBASE_FIRESTORE}
```

In my events screen I am then attempting to read the data (I know I havent written this code yet but can't reference the collection):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Image} from 'react-native'
import { FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, FIREBASE_APP } from '../firebase'

const EventsScreen = () => {

  const headerTitle = 'Events';

  const db = FIREBASE_FIRESTORE.collection('Events')

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavTopBar/>

        <Header title={headerTitle} />

        <SafeAreaView style={styles.content}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                {games.map((game, id) => (
                    <View style={styles.eventCard}>
                        <Text>{game.title}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.eventInfo}>
                            <Image source={getImageSource(game.homeTeam)} style={styles.flag} />
                            <Text>{game.dateStart}</Text>
                            <Image source={getImageSource(game.awayTeam)} style={styles.flag} />

                        </View>
                    </View>
                ))}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

> The error message I get is that FIREBASE_FIRESTORE.collection is not a
> function (undefined).

I know my firebase credentials are working as I have hooked up the Firebase Auth login, and the package is also downloaded and is in the node_modules/@firebase/firestore file in the app.

Appreciate it is something small but struggling to find the solution. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the (newer) modular API to access Firebase. In that API `collection` is a top-level function, rather than a method on the Firestore object. So instead of

```
const db = FIREBASE_FIRESTORE.collection('Events')
```

Use:

```
const db = collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, 'Events')
```

This is a common mistake, so I recommend reading [upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) to learn about the difference, and to then keep the documentation handy - as that has examples for both API syntaxes. My change above is based on this example in the [modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-modular-api_2) and [namespaced API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-namespaced-api_2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and pointing me to the correct resource, it has been really helpful. In the end, I wrapped the reference in a getDocs(). ```const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, 'Events'))```.... finding it a minefield but hopefully a turning point thanks to your help